# Change the size of table when an mouse is on image

Tags: html

I have a table in my html page with some columns in it. I want to give it's height and width as "0px" and when the mouse is on a specific image the height and width should be changed to 100px. The problem is that the table is not accepting the size of 0px. Kindly suggest useful measures

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide the table, you can use the following css property :

```
display: none;
```

And to show it back :

```
display: table;
```

Comment: actually the thing is I'am looking for animation effect where the table seems to be coming from the left side of the screen